# Catch All Exceptions code in the Main is not catching events exceptions

Tags: java, exception, awt, try-catch

Iam trying to put a "catch all" code to catch any exception that happens in my code so it can be sent to server.  Basically, the code below is the code of my Main. This creates a Jframe with buttons. When I click on one of the buttons, I am causing a crash (dereference a null pointer).  Howeever that exception is not being  caught in the code below and instead is displayed in my consol.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {


        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                    JFRAME_MAIN = new MainHomePage();
                    JFRAME_MAIN.setVisible(true);

            }
        });

        } catch (Exception ex) {

          System.out.println("Exception caught");   // <--- This is not being hit
        }

}
```

Any idea why or how to resolve this?

Thanks

PS:  I didnt put the code of the class MainHomePage because it is big class that setup layout and add buttons with their action listeners. In one of these listeners, I have the crash happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is not caught because it is not thrown by the code inside your try-catch block. The button click is not handled by this code, it is handled by an `ActionListener`. The code in the listener is throwing the exception.

The `invokeLater` method simply adds a `Runnable` to the queue, the act of adding that `Runnable` is successful and does not therefore generate an exception. See [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)).

Add a try-catch inside your listener code that handles your button click and you should be able to catch the exception - look for an `actionPerformed` method.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try{
        // your logic here
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        // do something to handle the exception here
    }
}
```

**EDIT (responding to comment):**

If you want to handle all uncaught exceptions in a single place you could do something like this:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Caught exception: "+e.getClass().getName());
        // do something else useful here
    }
});
```

You would place that code inside your main method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have so many listeners km my code, I have to add to each one of them? Is there no way to add it to a single place so I catch any exception thrown by my application?